# Authenticate Radius with LDAP Group

Tags: centos, ldap, freeradius2

I'm trying to authenticate specific LDAP group with FreeRadius.

I need to apply this checking inside a virtual-server, as there are two different groups and i'm using a single Unix Box.

Any suggestions of how to do this!.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the authorize section

```
authorize {
    if (!(LDAP-Group == '<group name>')) {
        reject
    }
}
```

Group name can be a name, or DN. In version 2 the heuristic is pretty simple, it just checks for the presence of a comma to determine if its a DN.